# Core synchronization problem with UNIX domain datagram socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, posix

UPDATE:  I transferred this question to include a minimal example, at [UNIX domain datagram socket -- server does not receive all records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61903585/unix-domain-datagram-socket-server-does-not-receive-all-records)

This is a question regarding architecture when using UNIX domain datagram sockets.

I have a multicore program that uses a UNIX domain datagram socket.  Multiple cores send records with sendto and one core receives records with recvfrom and processes the records sent by multiple clients.  The program processes a data series in a loop and at the end of each iteration the cores send data to the socket.  In the original design there was no lock where the cores send data because that would defeat the purpose of the socket.

The code is a shared object written in NASM called by a C wrapper, and the socket handing functions are all C programs that were linked into the NASM shared object.  The C socket functions are called from NASM.

At the send side:

```
push rcx
push r10
push r11
mov edi,[socket_client_fd]
mov rsi,[rbp-24]
mov rdx,720
mov rcx,[socket_server_addr]
call [rel client_send wrt ..got]
pop r11
pop r10
pop rcx

ssize_t client_send(int sfd, const void * buf, size_t msgLen, const     struct sockaddr * svaddr)
{

    int64_t alen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_un);

    ssize_t result = sendto(sfd, buf, msgLen, 0, svaddr, alen);

    if (result != msgLen)
        return 0;

    return result;
}
```

At the receive side (a separate core to receive records, organize them in core order and write to buffer):

```
mov rdi,[socket_server_fd]
lea rsi,[socket_buffer]
mov rdx,720
push r10
push r11
push r12
mov rcx,[socket_client_addr]
sub rsp,480
call [rel server_receive wrt ..got]
add rsp,480
pop r12
pop r11
pop r10

int64_t server_receive(int64_t sfd, void * buf, int64_t msgLen,     const void * claddr)
{
    socklen_t * len = (socklen_t * ) sizeof(struct sockaddr_un);
    int numBytes = recvfrom(sfd, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct  sockaddr *) claddr, len);

    if (numBytes == -1)
        return 0;

    return numBytes;
}
```

My problem is that without any lock, I found that not all cores were writing data.  I solved that by putting a simple user-space spinlock at the point just before the cores send their data to the socket:

```
add qword[cores_at_805],1
sl_805: ; spinlock to coordinate cores
mov rax,[cores_at_805]
cmp rax,3
jl sl_805
```

The spinlock only waits for all cores to arrive at that point -- in other words, for all cores to be instantiated and ready.  It does not wait on each subsequent iteration.  With that spinlock, all cores write data, but I get random data errors in the output.

If I run with only one client core and one server core there is no problem, so this is an issue of multicore communication with sockets.

My questions are:

1. Given the architecture I described above, why do I not get all cores sending data to the socket without a spinlock?
2. Why do I get random data errors in the output data with the spinlock?

I know the code above is not reproducible -- it only describes the client-server architecture.  I am posting this as a question of what the problem is with my architecture in client-server processing in the UNIX domain.

Thanks for any ideas on this problem.

Comment: Some details would be useful here. Are you using exactly one send process per core? (And do you lock each process to a processor?) Are you sending in a hard loop? Any other details you care to reveal?

Comment: Yes, one send process per core.  The affinity is set for each thread to be assigned to a separate core.  What do you mean by hard loop?

Comment: The socket is opened in blocking mode (the default).

Comment: I mean, do you just send requests as fast as you can?

Comment: With respect to the one process per loop question: Is the server running on the same machine? What else is running on the machine? Did you leave a core free for these processes?

Comment: I don't have any delay or "throttling" on the send requests.  In doing further work today, I found that without the spinlock only core 0 sends messages to the buffer.  With the spinlock is behaves as described above.

Comment: Everything is processed with multiple threads each assigned to a separate core, all in the same process; three cores are clients and one is the server.

Comment: I'm working now on a minimal reproducible example, but part of it is in NASM.  My primary concern now is why, without the spinlock, only core 0 sends records to the socket and with the spinlock they all send records, but with random data errors.

Comment: OK, I'll wait for the [mre]. Also, when you post it, describe what sort of data errors you are experiencing. Thanks.

Comment: I noticed that I am using the same file descriptor for all client sockets.  I don't think that's right -- I think each core needs its own file descriptor for the client socket.

Comment: This question has been updated and transferred to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61903585/unix-domain-datagram-socket-server-does-not-receive-all-records.